# Retrofit Android: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Tags: android, retrofit

I have coded an app with request to api for getting data.
I created a request by using Retrofit module in Robospice lib, it works well with Android api 16 - 22, except Android 4.4. I don't know why request failed, retrofit error is:
"com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"ư

I try to search this question in this page, but I didn't find any solution for my problem.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the response of your request. It is returning a String instead of a json object.

Set your log level to full and inspect the response:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    **.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)**
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .build();
```

Comment: The response of my request is true. I think this problem about Retrofit lib, because the request is not working with Android 4.4

Comment: `true` is not a valid json. That is the problem...

The response need to be something like {"response": true}

Comment: I found the problem, because of 3G connection, received package has something wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: *true is not a valid json* yes it is